# Google Voice Upgrade: Get a new number from Google or use my mobile number?

Tags: nexus-one, google-voice

Google voice added an upgrade recently, in which they allow to choose whether you want to use your own mobile number or get a new Google number.

[image]

Will I be able to activate my android with either one of the options? Is there a good reason why to prefer one over another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Choosing your Google number](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en_US&answer=150640) page in their help section. Specifically, have a look at the "Learn more about the difference between the two options" expandable link.

The gist is that unless you have Sprint, choosing to use your mobile number will simply allow you to **port** your mobile number and turn it into your GVoice number or continue using GVoice Lite. This means you lose your mobile number for your cell plan, which is probably not what you want in most cases.

If you have Sprint then you can choose to have your GVoice number be a copy of your actual mobile number, allowing GVoice communication to essentially appear as though it originated from your mobile phone (among other things, explained more at [About Google Voice on Sprint](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?answer=1207070)).